# Reading values sequential from a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table structure which is generated based on the selection from a UI and it is stored as it has been generated from UI. This is basically store query sequence.

e.g

> (( Condition AND Condition) OR ( Condition ))

```
Id  ConditionType Value         Brackets
 1     NULL        NULL           (
 2     NULL        NULL           (
 3     NULL        Condition      NULL
 4     AND         NULL           NULL
 5     NULL        Condition      NULL 
 6     NULL        NULL           )
 7     OR          NULL           NULL
 8     NULL        NULL           (
 9     NULL        Condition      NULL
10     NULL        NULL           )
11     NULL        NULL           )
```

From the above information I need to generate an index as :

```
Id  StartIndex   EndIndex
1     1           11
2     2            6
3     8           10
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: how the output comes from input of your sample data? give some idea

Answer (score 2):

Edit: In the 1st version, I missed taking into account the nested levels.  This one I tested :)

I work on DB2, so you'll likely have to refactor this for sql-server if it doesn't support a LATERAL join, but this one produced the correct results with your set of values on DB2:

```
with CTE_ONLY_BRACKETS as (
  select * 
  from   MYLIST 
  where  Brackets in('(',')')
) ,

CTE_NEST_INCREMENT as (
  select   Id
          ,Brackets
          ,case when Brackets = '(' then 1 else -1 end as NEST_INCREMENT
  from     CTE_ONLY_BRACKETS 
) ,

CTE_NEST_LEVEL as (
  select    Id
           ,Brackets
           ,S.NEST_LEVEL 
  from      CTE_NEST_INCREMENT C
  cross join lateral (
    select  sum( NEST_INCREMENT ) as NEST_LEVEL
    from    CTE_NEST_INCREMENT S
    where   S.Id <= C.Id
  ) as S

)

select   row_number() over() as Id
        ,L.Id as StartIndex
        ,R.Id as EndIndex
from     CTE_NEST_LEVEL R

cross join lateral (
  select L.Id
  from   CTE_NEST_LEVEL L
  where  L.Brackets = '('
    and  L.Id < R.Id
    and  L.NEST_LEVEL = R.NEST_LEVEL + 1
  order by L.Id desc
  fetch  first row only
) as L

where    R.Brackets = ')'

order by L.Id
```

Comment: Your query executes just fine in Sql Server as well. It gives as output (1, 1, 11), (2, 2, 10), (3, 8, 6). I think this is not the desired result.

Comment: Interesting. Which DB2 version supports lateral joins?

Comment: I work on DB2 on System i at version V7R1, which supports lateral joins.

Comment: I'd be surprised if recent versions of DB2 on other platforms do not support lateral joins. DB2 on System i tends to be behind the other platforms in terms of query capabilities, but ahead of the other platforms in that it runs more on auto-pilot and requires less manual administration.

P.S. For SQL-SERVER, remove the "fetch first row only" reference and replace "select L.Id" with "select top 1 L.Id" in that same join query. A quick Google search makes me think CROSS APPLY is the SQL-SERVER equivalent of LATERAL JOINs.

Comment: If CROSS APPLY doesn't do a good job at replacing the LATERAL joins, an alternative is to remove those LATERAL joins and use sub-queries in the select column lists instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @SampleDate TABLE (Id INT, ConditionType VARCHAR(10), Value VARCHAR(10), Brackets VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @SampleDate VALUES
(  1, NULL , NULL           , '('),
(  2, NULL , NULL           , '('),
(  3, NULL , 'Condition'    , NULL),
(  4, 'AND', NULL           , NULL),
(  5, NULL , 'Condition'      , NULL), 
(  6, NULL , NULL           , ')'),
(  7, 'OR' , NULL           , NULL),
(  8, NULL , NULL           , '('),
(  9, NULL , 'Condition'    , NULL),
( 10, NULL , NULL           , ')'),
( 11, NULL , NULL           , ')')

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT * FROM @SampleDate T1 
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT SUM (CASE 
                            WHEN Brackets = '(' THEN 1 WHEN Brackets = ')' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) Inx 
                FROM @SampleDate T2
                WHERE T1.Id >= T2.Id ) X
)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY X1.Id) AS Id,
    X1.Id StartIndex, 
    T.Id EndIndex 
FROM CTE X1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE X2 
                WHERE X2.Brackets =')' AND X2.Id > X1.Id AND X2.Inx = X1.Inx - 1 ORDER BY X2.Id ) AS T
WHERE 
    X1.Brackets ='('
```

Result:

```
Id                   StartIndex  EndIndex
-------------------- ----------- -----------
1                    1           11
2                    2           6
3                    8           10
```